# Unity 2D Android Limit GameObject transform horizontal

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, limit

Is there a way to limit the transform of a game object on the x axis? I am using GUI Textures as buttons to slide a game object right and left, but I don't want to it to slide outside of the screen view. Any advice is appreciated.

```
public float moveSpeed = 0.5f;

    void Update () {
    float horiz = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(horiz * moveSpeed,0,0));
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work:

transform.Translate(new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(horiz, minx, maxx) * moveSpeed,0,0));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Mathf.clamp()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) method.

Example:

```
float xPos = Mathf.clamp(xPos, minX, maxX);
```

This makes sure that if `xPos` goes below `minX` it will be set to `minX` and if it goes above `maxX` it will be set to `maxX` meaning that `xPos` can never be higher than `maxX` or lower than `minX`.

Comment: I finally got Mathf.Clamp to work. Thanks everyone for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to put game objects (ex. cube) as boundary of the screen. That way, you cant move your game object outside the screen, because it will collide with the boundary and stop going outside the screen.

Comment: Tried that. This object is set to destroy anything it collides with.

Comment: Then give a condition, if it collides with a game object with tag "boundary" for example, then don't destroy it.

Comment: I did that also. It didn't destroy it, but the object still passed through the boundry, even though the boundry has a rigid body and box collider. The colliders on the game object also have a rigid body and box collider. I also tried Mathf.clamp() and that didn't work.